# How to convert byte array value to float In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a list [142, 65, 110, 51] it needs to be converted to a float similar to `c_float` from `ctypes` lib. I don't know the logic for c_float.

I am trying to use module `struct`:

```
import struct

x = [142, 65, 110, 51]
ans = 0
for i, v in enumerate(x):
    ans += (v << (8 * i))

combined = ans  # 862863758

buf = struct.pack("d", combined)

fl = struct.unpack("ff", buf)
print(fl)
```

I get `(-32768.0, 25.21441650390625)`, but I need a single float value.

In short I want something like `[142, 65, 110, 51] => 0.0003232(some float value)`.

Comment: "but i need a single float value" - which one in this case ?

Comment: @frederic single value means  [142, 65, 110, 51]  => 0.0003232 something like that.

Comment: There are numerous functions which will map 4 bytes to a float. Are you looking for a specific float (e.g. the one in which those bytes are its underlying representation as an IEEE single-precision float)? "something like" is too vague to work with.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am looking for similar technique as c_float from ctypes python lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `f` rather than `ff`:

```
import struct

x = [142, 65, 110, 51]
fl = struct.unpack("f", bytes(x))
print(fl)
```

Which prints `(5.54733148305786e-08,)`

Note that you can skip your `ans` variable completely and directly convert `x` to a bytes object which can be unpacked.

Answer (score 3):

```
import struct

x =  [142, 65, 110, 51]
ans = 0
for i, v in enumerate(x):
    ans += (v << (8 * i))

combined = ans  # 862863758

buf = struct.pack("I", combined)
fl = struct.unpack("f", buf)
print(fl[0])  #  --> 5.54733148305786e-08
```